# AAD dynamic device group acording to principal user's domain

Tags: azure-active-directory, intune

I want to create a dynamic group based on the domain of the primary user assigned on the device.
I have managed to create a group with all the devices with the following dynamic membership rules:

`(device.devicePhysicalIDs -any (_ -contains "[ZTDId]"))`

I have users from two domains in my AAD, for example:

- domain1.com
- domain2.com

What I want is to create a group called "Devices - Domain1" and another called "Devices - Domain2".
In "Devices - Domain1" I want the devices to be linked to users who have domain1 in their username, for example pepe@domain1.com
And the same for domain2.

I don't know how to add the users part.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

•   Users and devices cannot be in the same group according to the architecture and given provisions in Azure AD and Intune. Dynamic group can be either user based, or device based but you can't mix both users and devices in the same group.

•   Though, according to your query, you can get a list of the devices and their associated primary users for those devices through a powershell script as below. Through the output of this script, you can manually create the groups according to your requirements.

```
#Get All Windows 10 Intune Managed Devices for the Tenant

  $Devices = Get-Win10IntuneManagedDevice

  Foreach ($Device in $Devices) {

    Write-Host "Device name:" $device."deviceName" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $IntuneDevicePrimaryUser = Get-IntuneDevicePrimaryUser -deviceId $Device.id
  #Check if there is a Primary user set on the device already

    if($IntuneDevicePrimaryUser -eq $null){

        Write-Host "No Intune Primary User Id set for Intune Managed Device" $Device."deviceName" -f Red

    }
```

•   Also, you can create a user group based on the user’s domain by classifying through the User Principal Name attribute in dynamic user group expression. You can do this by setting the property column as ‘userPrincipalName’ attribute, operator should be ‘contains’ and the value should be domain name in ‘@yourdomain.com’ format. This will create a user group with the specified domain containing all users of that domain.

Please refer to the below links for official documentation: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-membership

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddeviceregisteredowner?view=azureadps-2.0

Thanking you,